# How to force an anchor tag linking to a video to open in a phone default video player

Tags: javascript, html, video, mobile-phones

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CH1XGdu-hzQ?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0">linkimgthumb</a>
```

Currently, my markup contains a image link to a video. When click, it uses fancybox to popout the video. However on phones I want the link to open up in the phones native video player.

I know if I wrap it around an < iframe > tag it does the effect I need but I really want to keep my html the same. Does anyone know a solution? using JS or something?